# multiple checkboxes. only one is selected. how to get its value

Tags: java, android, checkbox

i have this code:

```
CheckBox aud = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.aud);
CheckBox cad = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cad);
CheckBox usd = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.usd);
CheckBox gbp = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.gbp);
CheckBox eur = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.eur);
```

and this:

```
int m = 0;
if (aud.isChecked()){
    m+= 1;

    }
if (cad.isChecked()){
    m+= 1;

}
if (usd.isChecked()){
    m+= 1;

}
if (gbp.isChecked()){
    m+= 1;

}
if (eur.isChecked()){
    m+= 1;

}
if (m > 1){
    aud.setChecked(false);
    gbp.setChecked(false);
    usd.setChecked(false);
    cad.setChecked(false);
    eur.setChecked(false);
    m = 0;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please select only one currency",           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }if (m == 0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a currency", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                this.currency = //add the value of the selected checkbox
```

I need to add the value of the only selected checkbox to the currecny variable. I managed to check if there is only one selected, but i cannot figure out how to get the value of the selected one and place it in a variable called currency which is a class attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `RadioGroup`

```
RadioGroup rd= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             // rb.getText() = to get Value 
            }
        });
```

xml :

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="CAD" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EUR" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TUN" />
    </RadioGroup>
```